# Customize schema names in Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I use generic type to share common properties in my response types, but I don't like the way Swashbuckle generates schema types from generic type (it concatenates the name of the type parameter in front of the container type name). Is there a way to override this behaviour?

Comment: An only description will not help us to assume what actual thing you are trying and what causes the issue. 
Could you please share what you have tried already?
 We could help you check your sample code and based on that we could try to provide suggestions that might help you to fix your issue.

Comment: Basically, if I have something like `Page<T>` model and I have an endpoint that returns `Page<User>` Swashbuckle will generate a schema named `UserPage` for that type. In this particular case it doesn't look too bad, but there are some cases when the generated schema name looks not so good.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `CustomSchemaIds`.

```
.AddSwaggerGen(options => options.CustomSchemaIds(selector => selector.FullName));
```

Use your own approach instead of `selector.FullName`.